# Consuming JSON with an array in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

On the webpage I am POSTing some JSON using jQuery:

```
$.post('/url', data);
```

My data is a javascript object that contains some values and an array. `JSON.stringify(data)` looks like:

```
{"favoriteAnimal":"piglet", "okayAnimals":["cats","dogs"]}
```

I'm consuming this JSON in a NodeJS webapp using ExpressJS (which is wired up with the body-parser middleware). I can retrieve the favorite animal like `req.body.favoriteAnimal` and it gives me the string `piglet` which is all fine and dandy.

But how do I access the values in the array?

```
req.body.favoriteAnimal // piglet
req.body.okayAnimals // undefined
req.body.okayAnimals[] // syntax error
```

This works...

```
req.body['okayAnimals[]']
```

...but smells fishy. It also won't return an array if the original data that is being POSTed contains only one element in its array (it just returns a single string).

Is there something going on with the the jQuery encoding of the JSON or something going on with the decoding in ExpressJS that's preventing me from accessing it like `req.body.okayAnimals` and getting an array every time?

Comment: hmmm... that doesn't sound right at all.... `req.body.okayAnimals` shouldn't be `undefined` given that json string.

Comment: Are you sure `data` is json (a string) and not an object? As a matter of fact, i'm positive it's an object and not a string, because that explains the behavior you are seeing. It gets turned into form parameters if it's an object: `favoriteAnimal=piglet&okayAnimals[]=cats&okayAnimals[]=dogs`

Comment: `typeof(data)` returns an `object` so you are correct, it is not a string

Answer (score 2):

Kevin's answer almost got me there.

`$.post('/url', JSON.stringify(data))` will send a string which is one step closer. Unfortunately jQuery's `$.post` sets the wrong header

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

which ExpressJS's body-parser will not handle appropriately. You end up with

```
req.body={"{\"favoriteAnimal\":\"piglet\",\"okayAnimals\":[\"cats\",\"dogs\"]}":""}
```

I rewrote how I was sending the data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/url',
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json'
})
```

I saw that my browser was sending the correct headers

```
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

And observed

```
req.body={"favoriteAnimal":"piglet","okayAnimals":["cats","dogs"]}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! For the past hour I've been searching for a solution to this same problem. I couldn't figure out the right Google terms. Now I learned that I was so accustomed to just passing string data as object/json I forgot they weren't the same thing (or context, or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects and JSON are two very differen things, which is the root of the problem you are seeing. What you are passing to `$.post()` is actually an object, not json, and is therefore being converted to a paramstring by jQuery before being sent to node. In this case, the paramstring is:

```
favoriteAnimal=piglet&okayAnimals[]=cats&okayAnimals[]=dogs
```

which of course explains why an `okAnimals[]` property exists on the body.

I'm surprised that the middleware you are using to parse the body isn't picking that up properly, but regardless you should instead pass a json string to `$.post` if you want to send it as is.

```
$.post('/url', JSON.stringify(data));
```